# How to restrict the value inside a textbox for a range of values from 1-999 using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to have a text box which accepts numeric values between 1-999 using javascript and keypress event has to be used as uswr should not be allowed to enter o in the textbox itself but say foreg 106 should be an allowed value.currently i am able to resrict 0 then it is not allowing user to enter 0 for later numbers also as it is not allowing to enter 105 i am using icefaces so cannot use html5 here and moreover has to implement using js and using onkeypress event as user shud not be even allowwed to enter the value

Code snippet is as follows which i have used onkeypress="if(event.which < 49 || event.which > 57) return false;

Answer (score 0):

Try this method...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateRange() {
        var txtVal = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value;
        if (txtVal >= 1 && txtVal <= 999) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            alert('Please enter a number between 1-999');//Also you can set this message to an existing label
            return false;
    }
</script>
```